# Fastest way to gather the unique data from a List in Java

Tags: java, performance, hashset

the basics of my question are that **given a List object in Java, what's the fastest way to return a collection of just the unique data?**

The more specific version, is that I have a 2d ArrayList (think of it like a table), and I want to loop through a given column index and return the unique data.

Here's my current setup:

```
public Set<Object> getDistinctColumnData( int colIndex ) { 

    //dataByIndex = List<List<Object>>

    Set<Object> colDistinctData = new HashSet<Object>( dataByIndex.size() + 1, 1f ) ;

    for( List<Object> row : dataByIndex ) { 
        colDistinctData.add( row.get( colIndex ) ) ;
    }

    return colDistinctData ; 

}
```

I got a small performance gain when I set the initial capacity to plus one the size of the non distinct set and the load factor to 1 (My thinking was it won't need to grow until it hits 100%, and that shouldn't happen even if the original set is already 100% distinct (or am I wrong?)).

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to give a reason?

Comment: I would use `(dataByIndex.size() *3/2)` for the initial size and leave the load factor, unless you expect lots of duplicates.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Work on something else.

Comment: I assume you did some profiling on your code (with jvisualvm for example) before you decided this was the troublesome part.

Comment: What kind of size is your list likely to be?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be way faster if you just have two unique Collections. Maintain your dataByIndex list, but also maintain a dataSet Collection (Set). When you insert into your dataByIndex list, also put into your dataSet Set. Then just use your dataSet where needed. The Set will maintain uniqueness by nature of being a Set.

Comment: I've thought about this. Moving the processing to when you add the rows. But the performance loss to adding data (which happens WAY more frequently than getting the distinct data) isn't really worth the gain in getting the distinct data.

Comment: Have you benchmarked the differences? It should be a relatively easy code change, and I think you might be surprised at the impact...

Comment: If, as OP said, inserting happens a lot more often than the distinct query (which is unusual, but we have no reason to doubt it), then indeed maintaining a separate distinct set could hit performance instead of improving it.

Comment: Why would it hit the performance to do it incrementally instead of batch, if there are no removals?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it doesn't make much sense in setting up the capacity and load factor to the values you specified. What hashing function do you use? May be it downgrades to linked list?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to get a further performance increase (on average) if you increase the initial capacity of the HashSet even more. This is because the distribution of the hash values of the objects in your list may be such that collisions are more likely.

For instance, given the following list, all but the first insertion will result in a collision, despite there being no duplicate values. (the Java hash function for integers is the value of the integer itself, and HashSet uses open addressing and linear probing in case of a collision).

```
[0,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

or even worse, because the each insertion has to check every non-free space before it can be inserted.

```
[0, 5, 25, 125]
```

In the last example 0 gets put in index 0. 5 goes to index 0 initially as 5 % size (ie. 5) equals 0, so then goes to index 1. 125 would go to index 0, but 0 is at index 0, 5 at index 1 and 25 at index 2. Meaning that after three checks 125 can finally be inserted at index 3.

If you increase the initial capacity then this decreases the probability of collisions (on average), and the decreases the number of checks required if a collision does occur (on average as well). By default java uses a load factor of 0.75 as a good balance between performance and memory usage. So divide by load factor of 0.75 and add 1 should give you a good initial capacity.